# Why there's not quick acess to our favorite questions?

Tags: feature-request

I wonder why there's no quick access to our favourite questions neither on the web app nor the mobile app, especially on the mobile app where I think it's not even possible (at least on Android). On the web app, it takes to navigate off the main board when it could be one more entry on the side panel, bellow "Unanswered" or one more tab at "Questions". That way we could even use filters (I guess).

I would find such quick access useful for sharing and rescuing questions (and answers). Many times, while I read need questions, I recall having marked as favourite a related question which comments and answers might help the OP or it might help to complete an existing answer but then I have a hard time recalling the title, the author or tags of that favourite. Perhaps it's just me. I use favourites as a repository for questions I find useful and interesting. Questions that worth having at hand.

Comment: At least in the web app, it is pretty simple to add a bookmark pointing to your favorite questions list (in any major browser), so you can always go there with one click. Same thing works in the Android app, I tried it, you may then open the "favorite questions" list there in a separate tab.

Comment: @DocBrown would you mind telling me how did you access the favourite questions in the Android App?

Comment: Under "Users", find your profile, switch to the "Activity" page. Then you may have to scroll down to find the drop-down box where you can choose the kind things you want to see. The drop-down has about eleven different options, ond of them is "Favorites".